# When is $\lfloor C^n \rfloor \mod b$ efficiently computable?

Tags: nt.number-theory, sequences-and-series, integer-sequences

For real irrational $C > 1 $ and natural $n,b$, define 
$a(C,n,b)=\lfloor C^n \rfloor \mod b$

> Q1 For which $C,b$ is $a(C,n,b)$ computable in time polynomial
>   in $\log{n}$?

Searching in OEIS suggests that for $C \in \{1+\sqrt{2},1+\sqrt{3},(1+\sqrt{5})/2\}$, $a(C,n,b)$ satisfy linear recurrence with constant coefficients and
so it is efficiently computable over the integers and all bases $b$.

In OEIS:
[a(n) = floor(phi^n)](https://oeis.org/A014217)

[a(n) = floor((1+sqrt(2))^n)](https://oeis.org/A080039)

[a(n) = floor((1+sqrt(3))^n)](https://oeis.org/A080041)

For natural $k$, $a(b^{1/k},n,b)$ is related to the base
$b$ representation of $b^{1/k}$ so it is probably hopeless.

> Q2 Is $a(1+\sqrt{6},n,b)$ efficiently computable in some base $b$?

(We couldn't find linear recurrence for it)

> Q3 Except linear recurrences, are there other islands of tractability
>   for algebraic $C$?

In comments @user44191 asked about specific constant near $1.75$.

We couldn't find linear recurrence, but got degree 2 relation
factoring into linear factors, which might be hint:

```
0 == (2*a(n + 2) - 3*a(n + 1) - 3*a(n - 1) - a(n - 3) + a(n) - 2) *
         (a(n + 1) - a(n - 1) - a(n - 3) - a(n) - 1)
```

Computational bugs are possible.

Comment: For algebraic $\alpha$ such that $|\alpha| > 1, |\alpha'| < 1$ for all conjugates $\alpha'$, I suspect it should be easily computable; this is true for the examples given.

Comment: I should note that I assumed $\alpha$ is an algebraic integer. The above may be somewhat overly general; a sufficient restriction is that there is a unique conjugate of second-largest magnitude (which, necessarily, will be real). In that case, there will be a clear linear recurrence. It may still be possible to get a linear recurrence otherwise; I don't have any examples with 2 roots of the 2nd largest magnitude off the top of my head, but it might be worth investigating those.

Comment: An example to test: the unique positive root of $x^3 - 2x^2 + x - 1$; I think that computing $\lfloor C^n \rfloor$ is equivalent to determining whether $n \text{arg}(\alpha')$ has positive cosine, where $\alpha'$ is either nonpositive root.

Comment: @user44191 I edited with partial results about the test.

Comment: For the $\alpha$ I wrote above, there is a degree 6 relation that use only 4 terms that's true for sufficiently large $n$: if $b(n) = a(n + 3) - 2 a(n + 2) + a(n + 1) - a(n)$, then $\prod_{i = -2}^3 (b(n) - i) = 0$. This is because $b(n)$ is an integer and because $a(n) - \alpha^n$ is either very close to $0$ or very close to $-1$.

Comment: @user44191 Could there be a pattern in "c(n)=a(An+B)"?